# CakePHP push notifications are repeating?

Tags: cakephp, google-cloud-messaging, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying send push notifications with CakePHP. The notifications are send but the problem is that all notifications are repeating. I cant understand why this problem.

I have a table to add devices of GCM (Google Cloud Messaging). After save the Model I do a SELECT in this table to get all `devide_id` of GCM saved and send the push notifications. The field `device_id` is unique in table. After to select I do a `foreach` to get devices and send the notifications, but this always repeating and send a lot of push to the same `device_id`.

How could I solve it ?

**Push Notification Class**

```
<?php

class Pusher{
    const GOOGLE_GCM_URL = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    private $apiKey;
    private $proxy;
    private $output;
    public function __construct($apiKey, $proxy = null)
    {
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
        $this->proxy  = $proxy;
    }
    /**
     * @param string|array $regIds
     * @param string $data
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function notify($regIds, $data)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::GOOGLE_GCM_URL);
        if (!is_null($this->proxy)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy);
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->getHeaders());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->getPostFields($regIds, $data));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === false) {
            throw new \Exception(curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        $this->output = $result;
    }
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOutputAsArray()
    {
        return json_decode($this->output, true);
    }
    /**
     * @return object
     */
    public function getOutputAsObject()
    {
        return json_decode($this->output);
    }

    private function getHeaders(){
        return [
            'Authorization: key=' . $this->apiKey,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];
    }

    private function getPostFields($regIds, $data){
        $fields = [
            'registration_ids' => is_string($regIds) ? [$regIds] : $regIds,
            'data'             => is_string($data) ? ['message' => $data] : $data,
        ];
        return json_encode($fields, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('Pusher', 'Plugin/Push');


class NoticiasController extends AppController {

public function add() {               
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {                
                $this->Noticia->create();                

                if($this->Noticia->save($this->request->data)){
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__("Save ok!"));
                    $this->sendPush();
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));                    
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__("Not save :("));
                }

            }
    }


/***************** push notifications ****************/
        private function sendPush(){            
            $apiKey = "AIzaSyCMZ6roIEpHsj5P8cgErgceerljerhaljh";
            //msg de push
            $message = array("title"=>"Title", 
                             "message"=>"Post a news",
                             "tickerText"=>"Post a news",
                             "url"=>"News");

            $this->loadModel('Device');
            $devices = $this->Device->query("SELECT device_id, status FROM devices Device WHERE status = 1");

            $pusher = new Pusher($apiKey);   

            foreach ($devices as $device){
                $pusher->notify($device["Device"]["device_id"], $message); 
            }               
        }
}
```